# Определить сколько элементов списка l1 содержится в словаре d1 (Питон) Использовать генераторы, решить задачу в одну строку

Tags: python

Определить сколько элементов списка l1 содержится в словаре d1 (Питон).
Использовать генераторы, решить задачу в одну строку

```
l1=list('abcdef')
d1=dict({'e': 1, 'f': 2, 'g': 3, 'h': 4, 'k': 5})
```

Comment: и ещё одно условие: **решить самостоятельно**

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = list('abcdef')
d1 = dict({'e': 1, 'f': 2, 'g': 3, 'h': 4, 'k': 5})


def foo(l1, d1):
    n = 0
    for l in l1:
        n += 1 if l in d1 else 0
        yield n


print(*foo(l1, d1))  # 0 0 0 0 1 2
```

P.S. Я в генераторах не очень силен, возможно так. В одну строку уже сами сделайте :)